# Trying to get the code to check if there are even brackets

Tags: java, if-statement, while-loop, boolean, brackets

I am currently trying to come up with a code that will scan a string
and check to see if there is an even number of open and closing brackets on each line. If so,  it would return true. (Excuse me for the incorrectness in formatting but I could not get the examples to properly take shape unless I identified it as code)

```
{}    // The code would return true    
{{}}
{}{}
{{{}{{}}}}


}     // The code would return false
{}
}}{
{{{}{}
```

What I tried so far:

```
    public boolean bracketsMatch(String brackets)
{
  int lb = 0;
  int rb = 0;
  int i = 0;
  while (brackets.charAt(i) == '{' || brackets.charAt(i) == '}' || brackets.charAt(i) == '')
  {
      if (brackets.charAt(i) == '{')
      {
        lb += 1; 
      }

      if (brackets.charAt(i) == '}')
      {
          rb += 1;
      }

      if (brackets.charAt(i) == '')
      {
          if (lb / rb == 2)
          {
              // Is it possible to get the code scan the next line to next line?
              // need an extra statement here for ^^ before I can place the if statement below
            if (bracket.charAt(i + 1) == '')
            {
              return true; 
            }
          }

            else 
          {
              return false;
          }
      }
      i++

  }
}
```

I apologize in advance for any experienced programmers as this would be an inefficient nightmare. I am relatively new to programming in general. I attempted to have the code check for the number of left brackets (lb) and right brackets (rb). Whenever the code came to an empty string, it would divide lb by rb. If the code did not equal 2, the code would return false. I probably have more than a dozen errors in this code, but I was wondering if there was any way to have the code go onto the next line to scan the next set of  brackets. Thanks for any help in advance.

EDIT 1:

```
public boolean bracketsMatch(String brackets)
{
  int balance = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < brackets.length(); i++)
  {
      char value = brackets.charAt(i);
      if (value == '{')
      {
        balance += 1; 
      }

      else if (value == '}')
      {
          balance -= 1;
      }

  }

  if (balance != 0)
  {
      return false;
  }

  else
  {
      return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: The first example returns true because there is an even number of brackets on each line. The second one may have a {} but most of the lines had an unequal amount of open and closed brackets

Comment: To verify that brackets are balanced you would want `lb == rb`, not `lb / rb == 2`.  Also this code won't compile as `''` is not a valid character literal.

Comment: Does `{` have to come before `}` as in normal bracket usage? In other words, what should be the result for this line: `}{`? Also, does your line contain only brackets, or could it be, for instance, `{ok}`?

Comment: For iterating through the chars of the string, I think the conventional way is `for (int index = 0; index < brackets.length(); index++)`. I’d go with this.

Answer (score 3):

This won't compile, as `''` is an invalid character literal:

> ```
> if (brackets.charAt(i + 1) == '')
> ```

And your current approach of counting opening and closing brackets,
and checking the value of `lb / rb` won't yield the right result.

You don't need to count the right brackets. You only need to count the open brackets, and reduce that count as they get closed.

Here's a sketch of an algorithm you can use,
I hope to not spoil the exercise:

1. For each character in the string
2. If it's an open bracket, increment the count
3. If it's a close bracket

   - If the open count is 0, there's nothing to close, so they are not balanced, we can stop
   - Decrement the count
4. After all characters, if the open count is 0, the brackets are balanced

As an additional code review note, this is bad in many ways:

> ```
>   if (brackets.charAt(i) == '{') {
>     // ...
>   }
>
>   if (brackets.charAt(i) == '}') {
>     // ...
>   }
> ```

What's bad:

- Calling `brackets.charAt(i)` repeatedly is unnecessary if the result will always be the same. Call it once and save the result in a variable.
- The two `if` conditions are exclusive: if the first is true, the second won't be true, so it's pointless to evaluate it. The second condition should be `if else` instead of `if`. And instead of an if-else chain, a `switch` could be more interesting here.
- Instead of calling the string `brackets`, it would be better to call it something more general. What if the actual input is "{something}"? Then it contains more than just brackets, but the algorithm would work just the same. Calling it brackets is misleading.

Comment: Upvoted for the sketch of a good algorithm for the purpose (no I don’t think you’re spoiling too much).

Comment: This is nice because you don't have multiple counters, or saving unnecessary values and break if there is no way it could be true. I added a workflow, to make your answer even better. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks @Thrasher for the attempt, a diagram like that could really enruch this answer. Unfortunately, the diagram you proposed doesn't correspond to the steps I described, it was incorrect at several points, so I had to reject it.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I changed my coding according to your advice but I'm still getting an error (which is something on my part; edits are in EDIT 1: if you feel kind enough to take a look ). My particular assignment told me to refer to the String as brackets. The current IDE I am using is an online one used to turn this assignment in, so it is very limited. I do have DrJava at hand, but this IDE cannot compile switch statements.

Comment: @HarryYou In your `else if (value == '}')`, after the `balance -= 1`, you need to add a condition: `if (balance < 0) return false`, because `balance < 0` means that there are too many `}`, you see? Another point about your edit, after the for loop, you can replace the if-else with a single line: `return balance == 0`. This is exactly equivalent to what you wrote, but shorter.

Answer (score 1):

## Alternative way to do

You can use Java Stack class [As it represent the List-In-First-Out stack of object].You can use the push and pop method of Stack class. Here is the implementation.

```
public class BracketMatching {

    public static boolean bracketMatch(String input){

        Stack<Character> st = new Stack<>();
    
        for(char c : input.toCharArray()){
    
            if( c == '{')
                st.push(c);
        
            else if(c == '}'){
            
                if(st.isEmpty())
                    return false;
            
                st.pop();   
            }
        }
    
        if(st.isEmpty())
        return true;

        return false;
    
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
    
        String input1 = "{}{{}}{}{}{{{}{{}}}}";
        String input2 = "}{}}}{{{{}{}";
    
        System.out.println(bracketMatch(input1));
        System.out.println(bracketMatch(input2));
    
    }
}
```

Comment: But why use a stack when you don't need one? And why store values you don't actually need? (If you did `st.push('x')` instead of `st.push(c)`, the program would still work, because the value doesn't even matter. Hence my objection: why bother storing it at all.)

Comment: It just an alternative solution. I was thinking of the case like "{ { } }", where there may any extra character between them like space and line break.

Comment: And how do the extra characters make any difference? (they don't)

Comment: I don't want to push the extra character into my stack like space, so I check for  **c== '{'** before the push and same goes for pop.

Comment: For the task as stated, this is needlessly complex. If you wanted to match both {}, () and [], a stack would be a good solution, only you would need to check that the char you pop off the stack is the expected kind of bracket.